# UITapGestureRecognizer on UICollectionView header not working?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am Trying to add a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the header of my UICollection view, but no matter what, I can't get the numberOfPostsViewTapped() function to fire off. I've been trying for hours, and have tried using other UI elements such as other views or labels in the header view, but nothing is helping. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind {

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader: // only checking header - no footer on this view

        // use an external class for the header UICollectionViewCell in order to set outlets on a non-reusable cell
        // if you try to set outlets on a reusable cell, such as a header, it will fail
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileCollectionViewHeader

        // dynamically set user profile information
        headerView.usernameTextLabel.text = user?.name
        headerView.numberOfPostsTextLabel.text = user?.numberOfPosts != nil ? "\(user!.numberOfPosts!)" : "0"

        let numberOfPostsViewSelector : Selector = #selector(self.numberOfPostsViewTapped)
        let viewPostsViewGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: numberOfPostsViewSelector)
        viewPostsViewGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        viewPostsViewGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true
        headerView.numberOfPostsTextLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        headerView.numberOfPostsTextLabel.addGestureRecognizer(viewPostsViewGesture)

        return headerView

    default:

        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")

    }
}
func numberOfPostsViewTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("HErE")
}
```

Comment: Does the expression `#selector(self.numberOfPostsViewTapped)` even compile? Looking at your code, the correct selector should be `#selector(self.numberOfPostsViewTapped(sender:))`.

Comment: I does compile... I replaced with your line and got the error `ProfileViewController.swift:117:66: Value of type 'ProfileViewController' has no member 'numberOfPostsViewTapped(sender:)'`

Answer (score 1):

Check your frames. Is your UICollectionView within its frame?

If a view is out of its frame, and doesn't clip to its bounds, it will show the view's contents, though user interaction will not work with it.

Comment: How would I check to see if it's within it's frame? It's appearing correctly [link](http://screencast.com/t/fkB1NSz09Q)

Comment: The simplest way to check it is probably to log the frame in somewhere like the UICollectionView's `layoutSubviews` like `NSLog(@"Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));` (Objective-C syntax, I don't know the Swift syntax for that, sorry, I'm sure you know what I mean though)

Comment: I added this comment:

        override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        print("LAYING OUT SUBVIEWS")
        print("Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(collectionView.frame));
    }

And this is what printed:

    LAYING OUT SUBVIEWS
    Frame: %@ {{0, 64}, {414, 607}}

I'm not sure what this means to my issue?

Comment: Ok, what I answered may not be your problem in this case. I know that when a view's contents extend out of it's superview's frame, even if the view's contents are still displayed they cannot be interacted with since they're outside that superview frame. That is what I thought might be your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to true to your headerView so that the tapping would reach your label which is a child of your headerView.

```
headerView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: I added that in but that didn't seem to have any effect. I'm not even sure how to start debugging this issue

Answer (score 1):

**Made few changes to your code and this worked for me**

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            guard
                let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "AddLinksReusableView", for: indexPath) as? AddLinksReusableView else {
                fatalError("Invalid view type")
            }
            let numberOfPostsViewSelector : Selector = #selector(self.imgVuTapped)
            let viewPostsViewGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: numberOfPostsViewSelector)
            headerView.profileImg.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            viewPostsViewGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            viewPostsViewGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true
            headerView.profileImg.addGestureRecognizer(viewPostsViewGesture)
            return headerView
        default:
            assert(false, "Invalid element type")
        }
    }
    @objc func imgVuTapped (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("HErE, Its working")
    }
```

**Happy Codding**